# What can be said about usefulness of two regression lines?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

How one can say that the regression equation $y$ on $x$ is more **useful** than the regression equation $x$ on $y$ as a predicting formula?

Comment: If you are trying to predict $y$ for new values of $x$, the regression of $y$ on $x$ will probably give you smaller *(expected sum of squares of)* errors.

Comment: Numerically, if the regression line has a very steep slope, then you may be better off regressing the other way around (and then correcting *ex post facto*).

Comment: You could use an orthogonal distance regression and there will be a unique line and this will make the problem disappearing I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

before randomly running a regression of $y$ on $x$ or vice versa. You should ask the question if there is any sense if using $x$ to predict $y$. Should there exist a relationship that should grant the predictability?

If you can answer this question then you can also know the usefulness of the regression. Other checks would be to see the following:

1. t-stats/p-values of coefficients, are they significant
2. do the computed coefficient values make sense or are the values absurdly high/low?
3. Are the residuals white noise? You can do a Q-Q plot to check for this.

Good Q-Q plot
[image: Good Q-Q plot]

Bad Q-Q plot

[image: Bad Q-Q plot]

Last thing to check is a good R-square value, subject to the fact that all the conditions above have "good" results.